# $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg() does not spin

Tags: jquery-mobile, spinner

I am having the same problem [this person describes](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/calling-the-spinner-programmatically).  The spinner on the showPageLoadingMsg() never spins!  Nobody ever answered his question, so I've got nothing to go on.  A  Does anybody have any ideas?

```
    $.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true;
    $.mobile.loadingMessage = "please wait...";
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
```

Edit: Here is the code that I am using to include jquery mobile, and jquery in my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery Mobile are you using? Also, where is this code running?

Comment: @Jasper- See my edits above.  I am using the latest jquery, and jquery mobile 1.0.1, both hosted at jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I upgraded to jquery mobile 1.1.0 and everything seems to be working fine now.  Here is the code I used for anybody else that might come across this:

in the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

the js:

```
$.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true;
$.mobile.loadingMessage = "please wait...";
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
```

Comment: Annoyingly verbose.. Thankfully, it looks like this is changing in 1.2 (which is not out as of this writing) http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: I'm using JQuery Mobile 1.1.1, and I'm still having this problem.